# Map that keeps its keys in order in which they were added in

Tags: data-structures, clojure

Is there data structure in Clojure that can fit this requirements:

- represent key-value pairs, i.e. be a map;
- `get` operation uses less then `O(n)`;
- keep keys in order in which they where added in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also have had need of this.  I have usually settled for map + a seq (that contains the order of the keys).  You could go all non-persistent and use LinkedHashMap but I think God kills a kitten if you do that.

Does Chris Houser's [finger tree implementation](https://github.com/Chouser/finger-tree) possibly fit the bill?

Comment: Yep, I had an idea to implement it as a map+seq pair, but I hoped Clojure has something ready-to-use. I'll take a look on finger trees implementation too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
user=> (sorted-map-by (fn [_ _] -1) :a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4)
{:d 4, :c 3, :b 2, :a 1}
```

Use a sorted map with a comparator that always returns -1. The newest entry will be at the beginning of the map and the oldest at the end.

Wrong answer. See the comments below.

Comment: Try retrieving a value from that map.  The results may surprise you.

Comment: It does! Why does it return `nil` all the time?

Comment: Because `sorted-map` uses the comparator to determine key equality.